# Nature of $ \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{ \cos(n) \sin(n+1) }{n} $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits-and-convergence

I'm trying to determine the nature of this series $ \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{ \cos(n) \sin(n+1) }{n} $, but I'm not getting anywhere. I've tried using the Abel and trigonometric formulas, but I can't find it. Does anyone have any ideas? Or even a solution? Please let me know.
Thank you very much and good evening.

Comment: Average value of $\cos(x)\sin(x+1)$ is $\sin(1)/2 \approx 0.42\ldots \neq 0$, so the sum should diverge. I think it wouldn't be too hard to prove using some sort of equidistribution (and, of course, irrationality of $\pi$), but I'll leave it to someone else.

Comment: Indeed, $\cos(n) \sin(n+1) = \frac{\sin(2n+1)}{2} + \frac{\sin(1)}{2}$.  The sum of a convergent series and a divergent series is divergent.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot my trigonomical formulas.

Comment: @Aleksei Irrationality of $\pi$ is not needed, by the way, only $1/\pi \notin \mathbb{Z} $

Comment: @FedorPetrov : What do you mean by "only $1/\pi\notin\mathbb Z$ [is needed]"? This just follows by [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test).

Comment: @IosifPinelis A bit more general series $\sum \frac{\cos a n \sin(an+b)}n$ (in our situation $a=b=1$) is convergent if and only if $b/\pi \notin \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 2):

You might try to regularize the sum,
$$S(\alpha)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{ \cos(\alpha n) \sin(n+1) }{n}=
-\tfrac{1}{4} i \left[e^{-i} \ln \left(1-e^{i (\alpha-1)}\right)+e^{-i} \ln \left(1-e^{-i (\alpha+1)}\right)-e^{ i} \ln \left(1-e^{-i (\alpha-1)}\right)-e^{ i}\ln  \left(1-e^{i (\alpha+1)}\right)\right]$$
$$=\text{Re}\, \biggl(\tfrac{1}{2} i e^i \ln \left[2 e^i (\cos 1-\cos \alpha)\right]\biggr),\;\;\alpha\neq\pm 1\;\;\text{mod}\;(2\pi).$$

Here is a plot of $S(\alpha)$.

[image]

Comment: Do you have a proof of this result?

Comment: it's a geometric series, $\sum_{m=0}^{ \infty} {z^n/ n}=-\ln(1-z)$ for any $z$ on the unit circle unequal to 1, see for example https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/118686/determining-precisely-where-sum-n-1-infty-fracznn-converges

Comment: No, this is not a geometric series.